# The compiler completely fails to recognise any function that is not stored in main.c in CLion

Tags: c, cmake, header-files, clion

I am using CLion and I am trying to use functions from different files within the same project in main.c. The compiler completely fails to recognise any function that is not stored in main.c

I get this:

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.2.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: ...\Temp\ccoXo0RG.o:main.c:(.text+0x4ac): undefined reference to `nodeCount'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.2.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: ...\Temp\ccoXo0RG.o:main.c:(.text+0x4e2): undefined reference to `inOrder'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.2.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: ...\Temp\ccoXo0RG.o:main.c:(.text+0x4f1): undefined reference to `printArray'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Below you can find the minimum reproducible example:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(Trees C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

set(PROJECT_HEADERS
        main.h
        trees.h
        basics.h
)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.c
        trees.c
        basics.c
)

add_executable(Trees ${PROJECT_SOURCES} ${PROJECT_HEADERS})
```

HEADERS BELOW

main.h:

```
#ifndef TREES_MAIN_H
#define TREES_MAIN_H

int pary(node* tree, int k);
int main(void);

#endif //TREES_MAIN_H
```

trees.h:

```
#ifndef TREES_TREES_H
#define TREES_TREES_H
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node node;
typedef struct nodeList nodeList;

struct node{
    int value;
    node* left;
    node*  right;
};

struct nodeList{
    int value;
    nodeList* left;
    nodeList*  right;
    nodeList* next;
};

/* some irrelevant declarations here */
int nodeCount(node* tree);
void inOrder(node* node, int* arr, int* pointer);

#endif //TREES_TREES_H
```

basics.h:

```
#ifndef UTILITY_FUNCTIONS_H
#define UTILITY_FUNCTIONS_H

#include <stdio.h>

/* some irrelevant declarations here */
void printArray(int* arr, int n);

#endif // UTILITY_FUNCTIONS_H
```

C FILES BELOW

trees.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "trees.h"

/* some irrelevant functions here */

int nodeCount(node* tree){
    if (tree)
        return 1 + nodeCount(tree->left) + nodeCount(tree->right);
    return 0;
}

void inOrder(node* node, int* arr, int* pointer) {
    if (node == NULL)
        return;
    inOrder(node->left, arr, pointer);

    arr[*pointer] = node->value;
    (*pointer)++;

    inOrder(node->right, arr, pointer);
}
```

basics.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* some irrelevant functions here */

void printArray(int* arr, int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i <n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[n]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

main.c:

```
#include "trees.h"
#include "basics.h"
#include "main.h"

int pary(node* tree, int k) {
    int n = nodeCount(tree);
    int pointer = 0;
    int* arr = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(*arr));
    inOrder(tree, arr, &pointer);
    printArray(arr, n);
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    node* tree = (node*) malloc(sizeof(*tree));
    tree->value = 1;
    tree->left = NULL;
    tree->right = NULL;
    pary(tree, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

I would be more very grateful for help because I cannot find information on what causes this. trees.c and basics.c do not have a main function inside.

Comment: ***The compiler completely fails to recognise any function that is not stored in main.c*** Do you get a linker error? Or what do you mean by the compiler does not recognise?

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us, just a simple "main" source file with another file containing a single function, plus the header file. Then do a verbose build (add `-DVERBOSE=True` in your build settings) to see the actual commands run. Copy-paste that (the full and complete build-log) into your question as well.

Comment: @drescherjm No. I added one and it changed nothing.

Comment: Sorry I changed the comment after I reread the question. Your question is not very clear and will not be fixable without more information / perhaps a build log.

Comment: @drescherjm @Some I have applied your suggestions, thank you. I added ```-DVERBOSE= TRUE``` to the build settings, but the only build output I get is the one added at the beginning of the post.

Comment: Are you sure that CLion is using your CMakeLists.txt in the first place?

Comment: Type `make clean && make VERBOSE=1`. Post the entire output of this.

Comment: Sorry for a stupid question, where do I type it?

Comment: CLion have a terminal tab, that opens a shell in the projects top directory (IIRC). The makefile is in a `cmake_something` subdirectory, so do `make -c cmake_something/Makefile clean`, and similarly for the other command.

Comment: Thank you. For me it's ```cmake-build-debug``` which has subfolders ```.cmake``` ```CMakeFiles``` and ```Testing```. I did what you suggested and got the following output: ```make : The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.```

Comment: The output you show is only a small part of the full and complete output. Please show the full and complete output, after a clean.

Comment: So that's what happens when you learn to rely on fancy tools like IDEs without a hint of understanding of how they actually work. When a fancy tool stops working, you have to call someone and wait until they fix it. Rinse and repeat ad infinitum. My advice for the long run is: set your IDE to one side, and learn how to use your compiler and associated tools directly, by editing your code in a simple text editor and typing commands in your terminal. But for now, you can add this line `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)` to your  CMakeLists.txt and rebuild from the IDE.